# Missing face texture

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

I downloaded a model and the face texture is not showing but im not really sure why,
anyone knows whats up?

[image: Missing face]

Here's the .blend file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the textures, so I can't make a final judgement, however:
your character uses 2 materials for the body, 9 for the eyes and 5 for the mouth. I am guessing this is supposed to produce facial expressions cartoon-style by switching the materials. I would strongly suggest to take all the different face meshes and split them into several objects, so you can easily hide the ones you don't need. Also the normals of those exchangeable parts are flipped, I don't think that was intentional.
With this setup (and I don't think this is the way you want to approach this in Blender) you're multiplying with an alpha value. Specifically with that of the animalboyaeye_alb.5.png, that image, or at least its alpha channel seems to be wrong, but I can't judge, because the textures aren't there.

Try separating the face parts, it might already make the problem go away. If not, send us the .blend with the textures.

Comment: Oh my bad, here's the full folder with textures included https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m62bp_RbcHUOnd1z9CK9qiaO_vENu8eC?usp=sharing

Comment: Id also have to add the fact that is a MMD model imported to blender with an addon, so you might find some weird values. Yesterday i saved that file with a little change that screwed the rigging but it shows the face correctly in the solid 3d viewport shading somehow. Here it is too: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/XMWXVXAJ

Comment: Ok last edit: I tried what you said and you are right, there were 9 different objects for the eyes stacked on each other. I separated them by material and left the only one that displays the texture correctly (animalboyaeye_alb.0.png).
May i ask you why the other 8 eye textures are missing? Feels like they should be included already in the .blend

Comment: I don't know what MMD is and how Blender treats the texture input.